# In R / writing loop function with external function inside

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I want to generate 100 queueing models with  queuecomputer https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/queuecomputer/queuecomputer.pdf (since the arrival and service times are random I would always get different results) and store a specific value of each of the lists in a separate vector. (queuecomputer always returns a list)
for example let

```
 n_customers <- 50
 arrival_rate <- 1.8
 service_rate <- 1
 arrivals <- cumsum(rexp(n_customers, arrival_rate))
 service <- rexp(n_customers, service_rate)
 queue_obj <- queue_step(arrivals, service, servers = 2)
```

then I would like to access summary(queue_obj)$mwt for all of the 100 samples and put that  value in a new vector.

What I have tried so far but it is not working:

```
 queuetmp <- function(n) {
  for (i in 1:n) {
 queue[[i]] <- queue_step(cumsum(rexp(50, 1/10)), rexp(50, 1/8), servers = 2)
 mwt[i] <- (summary(queue))[[i]]$mwt
 }
 return (mwt)
}
```

(since queuecomputer is a really new package many won't be familiar with it but the output is just a typical list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to move the index `i` inside and also define `queue` and `mwt` as empty lists first, i.e.:

```
library(queuecomputer)
n_customers <- 50
arrival_rate <- 1.8
service_rate <- 1
arrivals <- cumsum(rexp(n_customers, arrival_rate))
service <- rexp(n_customers, service_rate)
queue_obj <- queue_step(arrivals, service, servers = 2)
queue <- list()
mwt <- list()

queuetmp <- function(n) {
  for (i in 1:n) {
    queue[[i]] <- queue_step(cumsum(rexp(50, 1/10)), rexp(50, 1/8), servers = 2)
    mwt[i] <- (summary(queue[[i]]))$mwt
  }
  return (mwt)
}

queuetmp(10)
```

I appear to get output with a nontrivial answer, if that matches what you were expecting?

Answer (score 1):

Since [each iteration of the loop is independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) - this is something that could be run in parallel (Note: This particular problem doesn't need to be parallelized because it's so fast anyway).

Here is a very fancy and modern way to do this in R. It uses `future`, `purrr`, and `furrr` (a parallel version of `purrr`).

```
library(furrr)
library(queuecomputer)
library(future)
library(future.apply)
library(purrr)
```

We now set up system for sequential or parallel computation. The `::` just tell R which package to find the function. It's unnecessary here since I already ran `library(future)` but it's something I like to do to make everything clear. Also it can be important when you want to run things in parallel (see inside `queuetmp`), because the parallel R sessions might not have the same libraries loaded.

```
future::plan("sequential") # change this to "multisession" to run in parallel

n_customers <- 50
arrival_rate <- 1/10
service_rate <- 1/8
n_servers <- 2
```

We make a function `queuetmp` that returns the result we want. Notice that there is no looping or replication yet.

```
# We will put this inside the replicate function. 
queuetmp <- function(
  n_customers, 
  arrival_rate, 
  service_rate, 
  n_servers
  
){
  
  queue_output <- queuecomputer::queue_step(
    cumsum(rexp(n_customers, arrival_rate)), 
    rexp(n_customers, service_rate), 
    servers = n_servers
  )
  
  mwt <- summary(queue_output)$mwt
  
  return(mwt)
}
```

We make a partial function so we don't need to include the arguments everytime. The `!!` are called "bang bang". You can look them up.

```
partial_queue_fun <- purrr::partial(queuetmp, !!n_customers, !!arrival_rate, !!service_rate, !!n_servers)
```

The "bang bang" forces the variables to be evaluated so their values don't need to be looked up everytime. You can see the argument values (as the actual numbers) here.

```
partial_queue_fun
## <partialised>
## function (...) 
## queuetmp(50, 0.1, 0.125, 2, ...)
```

When we don't include the "bang bang" (see below), the numbers aren't saved, just their names, which might be a problem when computing things in parallel.

```
purrr::partial(queuetmp, n_customers, arrival_rate, service_rate, n_servers)
## <partialised>
## function (...) 
## queuetmp(n_customers, arrival_rate, service_rate, n_servers, 
##    ...)
```

Running the function is simple, since it is self-contained.

```
partial_queue_fun()
## [1] 1.723047
```

Now we put this into the parallel version of replicate.

```
n <- 100 # number of iterations

future_replicate(n, partial_queue_fun(), future.seed = 1)
## [1] 0.547223629 1.897130628 1.620501737...
# etc.... (93 more numbers)
```

There's a 100 values in total.

Comment: thank you very much for this insightful answer and the additional information, I learnt a lot! I didn't know the bang bang operator before

Comment: The partial thing isn't necessary at all! I don't know why I added it!